# how to enable access to a webform only from a link sent to user

Tags: 7, webforms

i'm planning to create a form with the webform module on D7.
i would like to be able to send via e-mail a link to that webform, but only those who receive that link (non-registered users) could access and fill the form. i don't like to expose the form to general public of the website.

i know how to do this with registered users, it would be straight forward with permissions, but don't know how to achieve this with non-registered ones.

what would be the way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by help of [Deeplink](https://drupal.org/project/deeplink) module. Module page explains -

> Sometimes you want to be able to give simple URL access to content
>   that would not normally be available to a particular user (or perhaps
>   someone not even registered with the site).
>
> Deep link module allows the direct access to a specific item of
>   content under certain circumstances and limitations. Such as one-off
>   or time-limited deeplinks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Webform per Email](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_per_email) module to send one time links to anonymous users via email.

> This module implements a permit based access system to allow anonymous users submit a [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) only if they display a valid one-time access permit.